Take shell cmd stdout_lines and create dict from output
I am using needrestart -b to get the following example output
NEEDRESTART-VER: 3.6
NEEDRESTART-KCUR: 5.14.0-362.24.1.el9_3.0.1.x86_64
NEEDRESTART-KEXP: 5.14.0-362.24.1.el9_3.0.1.x86_64
NEEDRESTART-KSTA: 2
NEEDRESTART-UCSTA: 0

How would one convert this into a dictionary for use in my playbook? I've done it before but I can't for the life of me remember how I did it. See my current playbook below. AI recommended the "from_yaml" but it didn't work.
---
- name: Reboot if necessary
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: true  

  tasks:
    - name: Install needrestart RedHat
      become: true
      when: ansible_facts['os_family'] == "RedHat"
      ansible.builtin.dnf:
        name: 'needrestart'
        state: latest # noqa package-latest

    - name: Install needrestart Debian
      become: true
      when: ansible_facts['os_family'] == "Debian"
      ansible.builtin.apt:
        name: 'needrestart'
        state: latest # noqa package-latest

    - name: Check if system needs to be rebooted
      become: true
      ansible.builtin.shell:
        cmd: needrestart -b        
      register: command_results
    
    - name: Convert previous output to dictionary
      set_fact:
        needrestart: "{{command_results.stdout_lines | from_yaml }}"      

    - name: Debug print needrestart results
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: needrestart['NEEDRESTART-VER']


A: The value of
command_results.stdout_lines is the YAML list. Nothing happens to the list when you filter it from_yaml. Use command_results.stdout instead
- set_fact:
    needrestart: "{{ command_results.stdout | from_yaml }}"

Details: Given the below file for testing
shell> cat needrestart.txt 
NEEDRESTART-VER: 3.6
NEEDRESTART-KCUR: 5.14.0-362.24.1.el9_3.0.1.x86_64
NEEDRESTART-KEXP: 5.14.0-362.24.1.el9_3.0.1.x86_64
NEEDRESTART-KSTA: 2
NEEDRESTART-UCSTA: 0

Please read it
    - command: cat needrestart.txt
      register: command_results

You can see that next to the YAML list in the attribute stdout_lines
  command_results.stdout_lines:
  - 'NEEDRESTART-VER: 3.6'
  - 'NEEDRESTART-KCUR: 5.14.0-362.24.1.el9_3.0.1.x86_64'
  - 'NEEDRESTART-KEXP: 5.14.0-362.24.1.el9_3.0.1.x86_64'
  - 'NEEDRESTART-KSTA: 2'
  - 'NEEDRESTART-UCSTA: 0'

there is also the YAML text bloc in the attribute stdout
  command_results.stdout: |-
    NEEDRESTART-VER: 3.6
    NEEDRESTART-KCUR: 5.14.0-362.24.1.el9_3.0.1.x86_64
    NEEDRESTART-KEXP: 5.14.0-362.24.1.el9_3.0.1.x86_64
    NEEDRESTART-KSTA: 2
    NEEDRESTART-UCSTA: 0

Now, you can use from_yaml to (quote):

Converts a YAML string representation into an equivalent structured Ansible variable.

For example,
  needrestart: "{{ command_results.stdout | from_yaml }}"

gives what you want
  needrestart:
    NEEDRESTART-KCUR: 5.14.0-362.24.1.el9_3.0.1.x86_64
    NEEDRESTART-KEXP: 5.14.0-362.24.1.el9_3.0.1.x86_64
    NEEDRESTART-KSTA: 2
    NEEDRESTART-UCSTA: 0
    NEEDRESTART-VER: 3.6

  needrestart['NEEDRESTART-VER']: '3.6'


Notes:

If you have a list only there are more options. You can convert the items to YAML dictionaries and combine them

  n3: "{{ command_results.stdout_lines | map('from_yaml') | combine }}"

gives the same result
  n3:
    NEEDRESTART-KCUR: 5.14.0-362.24.1.el9_3.0.1.x86_64
    NEEDRESTART-KEXP: 5.14.0-362.24.1.el9_3.0.1.x86_64
    NEEDRESTART-KSTA: 2
    NEEDRESTART-UCSTA: 0
    NEEDRESTART-VER: 3.6

  n3['NEEDRESTART-VER']: '3.6'


The next option is using the function dict on the split items. The below declaration also gives the same result

    n4: "{{ dict(command_results.stdout_lines | map('split', ':')) }}"


Example of a complete playbook for testing


- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    n1: "{{ command_results.stdout_lines | from_yaml }}"
    n2: "{{ command_results.stdout | from_yaml }}"
    n3: "{{ command_results.stdout_lines | map('from_yaml') | combine }}"
    n4: "{{ dict(command_results.stdout_lines | map('split', ':')) }}"

  tasks:

    - command: cat needrestart.txt
      register: command_results

    - debug:
        var: command_results.stdout_lines
    - debug:
        var: command_results.stdout

    - debug:
        var: n1
    - debug:
        var: n2
    - debug:
        var: n2['NEEDRESTART-VER']
    - debug:
        var: n3
    - debug:
        var: n3['NEEDRESTART-VER']
    - debug:
        var: n4
    - debug:
        var: n4['NEEDRESTART-VER']


